# Comparison between Pandas Dataframes and mark the differences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good afternoon.
I try to use Pandas dataframe to handel some data, and export as Excel with format/style, like when a cell fulfils a condition, mark a color,

my data looks like:

```
df1
BM       date        MY     VIN       SW1          SW2        ... SW12 
112220   12.02.2022  802    XXXXXXXX  10xxxxxx01   10xxxxxx02 ... 10xxxxxx13  
...
...
...
```

```
df2
Model       BM       MY        SW1          SW2        ... SW20       
BMWiX       112220   801       xxxxxxxx01   xxxxxxxx02 ... xxxxxxxx20
BMWiX       112220   802       xxxxxxxx01   xxxxxxxx02 ... xxxxxxxx20
BMWiX       112220   803       xxxxxxxx01   xxxxxxxx02 ... xxxxxxxx20    
...
```

I used to make the comparison Excel with VBA, works pretty good.
Logic is take one row in `df1`, check all values `SW1 SW2 ... SW12`, make sure they are `10 digits' string` values.

Then check the `BM + MY` with all rows in `df2`, if `BM + MY` are equal, then check the `SW` one by one, make sure `SW` in `df1` and `df2` be equal, if not, mark it in `df1`.

For example, if `SW1` in `df1` is `1234567890`, and `SW1` in `df2` is also `1234567890`, perfect, matched! But if `SW1` in `df2` is `0034567890`, then I shall mark `SW1=1234567890` in `df1` as red, means mismatch.

In VBA I can direcktly mark the color in excel, but in Pandas, I can't!
I have done the comparison part, but for the mark color part still not clear, I have tried using `df1.style.apply()` and `df1.style.applymap()`, but did not work.

I used a call back function

```
def color_red(s,threshold):
    items = s > threshold
    return ['color-background : red' if v else '' for v in items]

df1.style.apply(color_red, threshold=df2.iat[i_df2, c_df2])
```

it shown that
`AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'iat'`.

I also tried used a  seperate `dataframe` to store all mismatches, mark a mismatch with `'color-background : red'` in the corresponding dataframe, then use `df1.style.apply()`

```
df1_style
BM    date  MY     VIN       SW1                      SW2 ... SW12 
NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN      'color-background : red'  NaN ... NaN
...
...
...
```

But it still doesn't work.

So I have to come here to ask for help...

Or maybe I should use `openpyxl` to mark on a excel?

BR.

Comment: .iat return the value contains in the cell, and .style is a method for the dataframe. You should try something like : ```df.style.apply(lambda x: ["background-color: blue" if ... for _ in x], axis = 1)``` by replacing ... with you condition. (using ```x.iloc[i,c]```)

Comment: @AlexHhz hi Alex, thanks for your reply, I tried to understand it, but still no progress, I used ```df.style.apply()``` and also ```df.style.applymap()```, but I find out it hard to do that, because the dondition I am using is a value from another Dataframe, like ```df1.iat[i, c] != df2.iat[j, s]```, but for ```df.style.apply()``` and ```df.style.applymap()```, the function is callback function, I don't know whether it is possible to adjust ```df1.iat[i, c] != df2.iat[j, s]``` to a callback function. But anyway, thanks! I learned a lot!